# Animated graphics implementation dialog based MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Could anyone suggest me a particular way to implement animation in my Dialog-based mfc program? The animation that I am intending to add is like a construction digger machine graphic that would read the values of the machine parameters and change the shape of the graphic accordingly. Most of the information is read from a text file in terms of the parameters, so I just need to be able to get the animation working.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It would depend on the size and frame-rate you wish to get. It is not the same a 64x64 at 8 FPS than a 800x600 at 60 FPS animation.

Comment: I wouldn't mind a 400x480 image at any fps. But how does that affect what I would be drawing? I would be using Invalidate() anyways to refresh the OnPaint() function every single time the graphic needs to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, GDI is easy but ugly and quite slow, GDI+ is also easy, but nicer although generally slower. OpenGL or DirectX are much, much faster but quite hard to program. Other libraries, such as cairo, are also available.

I'd suggest to start with the easiest (maybe GDI+) and see if it is fast enough for you.

Do do that, just Invalidate() the control where you are drawing in a timer, (or when you receive new data), and paint the whole graphic in the OnPaint() function. A basic improvement is to Invalidate() only the region where the new data affects the picture.

If then you notice that your code is not fast enough, come back and ask how to improve it. A concrete example will make it easier to get a more useful answer.

Comment: I don't know about slow. The animation doesn't sound all that overwhelming. GDI and GDI+ will probably be fast enough (unless you seriously misuse GDI).

Comment: I'd try implementing that. Hope it works. I'll drop by a question on the forum if I get stuck somewhere. But thanks for the suggestion.

Cheers.

Comment: It is not so linear what technology is faster; it depends very much on the graphics board.

Answer (score 0):

there are lot of articles. Most of them based on drawing in device context

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/flickerfree.aspx
2. http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/article.php/c4879
3. http://www.codersource.net/mfc/mfc-gdi-plus/animation-control-mfc.aspx

Comment: I have looked into these. They don't exactly have what I need. Guess I need to do everything manually with position plotting.